Invoking Lambda function from another Lambda function consistently results in a strange HTTP 421 Misdirected Request error
I'm suffering from a bizarre undocumented HTTP 421 Misdirected Request error when trying to invoke Lambda functions from other Lambda functions via Python/boto3 (with InvocationType = 'Event') like so:
lambda_client.invoke(
    FunctionName   = my_lambda_function,
    Payload        = json.dumps('{'foo': 'bar'}),
    InvocationType = 'Event'
)

The error thrown is:
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (421) when calling the Invoke operation:

(With nothing printed beyond the colon.)
I believe my Lambda permission are in order too, as per below?
Execution role:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}

Execution role policy (inline):
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:lambda:MY_AWS_REGION:MY_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:function:MY_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Anyone have any idea?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/api/API_Invoke.html lists a bunch of possible error codes, but they do not include any mention of HTTP 421 or Misdirected Request. Worse, Googling "421" Lambda invoke does not seem to bring up anything relevant at all, either.

Any chance you are passing a weird character to FunctionName such as \n or %0a (new line symbol) ? I ask because I was able to repro the exact same error passing this as FunctionName: FunctionName='autho\n' (autho is the actual function name I am invoking, \n is what I added to repro the error)

@andresm53 You hit the nail on the head! I "solved" this problem earlier today —before I noticed your comment— by changing the value of the my_lambda_function variable assigned to FunctionName from an ARN value to just the name of the Lambda function; but this “solution” didn’t really make sense to me, because either way should be fine according to the official docs. And, in fact, they are; but —exactly as you suspected— that ARN value accidentally included a trailing newline character, whereas the function-name-only version didn’t.

While debugging I printed the values used to the console, but failed to notice the newline in fact causing a new line… BTW, the underlying cause was that I’m declaring these values in YAML conf files, but the pyyaml parser apparently doesn’t strip() any whitespace; which I’ve now dealt with by strip()ping all strings myself. Annoying that the SDK throws such a wild ondocumented error for something so asinine, but glad to have found the cause. In any case, thank you @andresm53!  If you write that as answer, I will accept it promptly!

I was able to repro the exact same error ClientError: An error occurred (421) when calling the Invoke operation by passing \n to FunctionName:
client.invoke(
  FunctionName='MyOtherFunction\n',
  InvocationType = 'Event'
)

MyOtherFunction is the name of the function I want to invoke, and \n is what I added to repro the error.
So, please make sure you are not passing weird characters to FunctionName such as \n or %0a (new line symbol).

You fooookin genius
